# play framework Java chunked response

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, streaming

I am trying for java  chunked response part of play framework. But it is not working .It seems like client side will start getting the data until all data is provided in server side.

Code is pretty much like this , passing an infinite string to chunks.

```
public static Result index() {
   // Prepare a chunked text stream
    Chunks<String> chunks = new StringChunks() {

        // Called when the stream is ready
        public void onReady(Chunks.Out<String> out) {
            while(true){
                 out.write("hello");
            }
        }
    };
   // Serves this stream with 200 OK
   return ok(chunks);
}
```

It just gets stuck forever, and I can receive nothing in browser or console.

Is it the right way to pass an infinite string like this ? 
If it is not , how can I pass infinite data or large file (chunked) to client side ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own stupid question. I blocked myself by making an infinite loop in its own thread.

Just create a new thread and everything will be fine